# Buttons in HTML cell on same line

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons inside the same table cell to edit and delete a user. Right now it is causing a line break instead of both being on the same line. Can I fix this? My code is in HAML for a Rails app and I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

users index page:

```
%h1.text-center Users
%br
.col-md-6.col-md-offset-3
  %table.table
    %th First Name
    %th Last Name
    %th E-Mail
    %th User
    %th Modify
    - @users.each do |user|
      %tr(id="user#{user.id}_row")
        %td= user.first_name
        %td= user.last_name
        %td= user.email
        %td= user.type
        %td{ min_width: '100px;'}
          =edit_user_button(user) + (delete_user_button(user) if is_admin?)
```

Here is the helper class that generates the buttons:

```
require 'action_view/helpers/url_helper'

module UsersHelper
  def edit_user_button(user)
    button_to 'edit', edit_user_path(user), class: 'btn btn-default'
  end

  def delete_user_button(user)
    button_to 'delete', destroy_user_path(user), 'method' => :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete #{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}?"}, class: 'btn btn-default'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not a line break, the table cell is just too small, so make that table cell wider.

```
%td{:min_width => "100px;"}
```

Comment: Hmm, still no luck - I just updated my code with the min_width added. Any ideas?

Comment: I think @Ixer was just giving you an example.  100px is probably not enough to accomodate 2 buttons inline, so if that's the value you used, it wouldn't have fixed it.  Have you checked the width of the table and this column in your browser inspector?  Also, this is probably unlikely, but check the "display" property on your buttons in your inspector.  They should be set to "inline", but if there is a rule somewhere in your CSS that is setting buttons to "block", this would also cause them to line-break like that.